# Ionic: show data rendered by php

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app and I want to populate one of it's pages with data I get with a php script. So, my php:

```
<?php 

    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'mypass';
    $client = new SoapClient('http://mywebsite.rs/api/soap/?wsdl', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

    try {
    $session = $client->login($user, $pass);

    $result = $client->call($session, 'api_category.rootcategories');
    print_r ( $result);

    $client->endSession($session);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Now. I want to print the result on my homepage. What's an easy way to output that? The problem is I don't know how to call that file from ionic framework. I do have some code, I worked on experimenting, but it's not working:

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http,$state ,$ionicModal,$ionicHistory,$ionicNavBarDelegate,SearchData,$window) {

```
$scope.categories = [];
var numberOfRow = 1;

var link = 'app/getAllCats.php';
$http.post(link).then(function (res){
  $scope.categories = res.data;
  for(var i = 0 ; i<res.data.length ; i++){
    if(res.data[i].is_active === 1)
      $scope.categories.push(res.data[i]);
  }
  arrayLength = $scope.categories.length;
  numberOfRow = ~~(arrayLength / 3);
   var div = arrayLength - numberOfRow;
   if(div <=2 || div >=1 ){
      numberOfRow = numberOfRow + 1;
   }
});
$scope.range = function(){
  return new Array(numberOfRow);
}
$scope.create = function(id){
  $state.go('fooBar',{category_id: id});
}
console.log($scope.categories);
```

})

Comment: Send data in the form of json then read in controller show in view.

Comment: How would I do that? Code example would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP Code, you should send the array in JSON format. Replace this line :

```
print_r($result);
```

with

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Then if you want to be able to use this result in the client side you have two choices, you can either ask PHP to declare the output as JSON to any client sending in a request by adding this at line 1 in your PHP file :

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Or ask JavaScript to parse the response string as a JSON Object by replacing this line :

```
$scope.categories = res.data;
```

By

```
$scope.categories = JSON.parse(res.data);
```

### PS: The following is not answering the question but still good to know

When using Ionic's (or more generally AngularJS's) `$http` for querying a PHP server, the request body is sent as a raw JSON string. Say you wanted to send the login and password via a form in your Ionic app :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user" />
<input type="password" ng-model="pass" />
<input type="button" ng-click="login()" />
```

with

```
$scope.login = function() {
  $http.post(link,
    {
      user: $scope.user,
      pass: $scope.pass
    }
  ).then(function(response) {
    ...
  });
}
```

then in PHP you would be tempted to get the sent login and password using `$_POST` while actually, you can't because `$_POST` superglobal is created by parsing the querystring in the body of the request

```
user=username
pass=P@s$W0rd666
```

while AngularJS's `$http` sends raw JSON as a string.

```
{
    user: "username",
    pass: "P@s$W0rd666"
}
```

This is pretty annoying but fortunately, PHP has another global variable for these situations : `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. So in your PHP code you would retrieve the user input by calling

```
<?php 
$postData = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, 1); // don't forget the second argument
$user = $postData['user'];
$pass = $postData['pass'];
?>
```

Sorry for the long post, I felt that I NEEDED to tell you this. I wish someone did when I was in your situation.

### Edit

You won't be able to store your PHP files in your ionic project's `www` directory. You need a separate web server. Also dont forget

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

on top of your PHP file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One thing though: link variable I'm using in http is not proper, and it seems like angular can't make requests to local PHP files. Am I right or is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, Ionic is served via Node.JS, you can definitely make `$http` request to local files (path is relative to `www` folder) but you wont be able to interpret PHP. You need to have a separate web server and call that address instead (and don't forget the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on top of your PHP along with the `Content-type: application/json`). I've edited my answer

Comment: Which means I can't do what I want in ionic. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: could you explain what you want to do exactly ? There might be a way